# Android things SIM700E LTE + GPS Driver

Tags: android, gps, driver, android-things, lte

I am trying to make a Prototype  using RPI3 and SIM700E module even after lot googling it Was difficult to figure out how the drivers will work 
.As per [linux](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7100E/how_to_use_the_sim7100_module_in_linux-driver-1.pdf) & [Android](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7100E/Driver/Android%20ril/How%20to%20use%20Android%20RIL%20V1.0.pdf) setup guide by simcom the USB interface has 6 virtual hosts

1. /dev/ttyUSB0-diag port for output developing messages
2. /dev/ttyUSB1- NMEA port for GPS NMEA data output
3. /dev/ttyUSB2-AT port for AT commands
4. /dev/ttyUSB3-Modem port for ppp-dial
5. /dev/ttyUSB4-audio port
6. /dev/ttyUSB5-Virtual Net card

but for this to work the Linux kernel must have the qualcomm gobi drivers, so i am not sure weather android things OS need these drivers or it Can work without it 
also according to the mobile android guide we have to modify some system files which do not exist in android things OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems, there is no SIM700E drivers in Android Things kernel and there is no way to add it now (from [here](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/)):

> Note: You cannot customize the behavior of device drivers in the Linux
>   kernel or Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) to add new functionality to
>   a device.

So, the easiest way to connect SIM700E LTE to RPI3 with Android Things is to connect SIM700E to Raspberry Pi via UART (BCM14, BCM15 pins on RPi and Tx Rx pins on SIM module) and write custom [User-space driver](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/) for SIM700E based on its AT-commads. For driver prototype you can use [contrib-driver/gps](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps) from official repo (it also uses UART and requires response parcing).

**Update** 
And also, you can use USB<->UART converters on RPi side to connect to SIM700 module if you lack of UARTs (USB<->UART converters are supported by Android Things) like in [that](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/usb-communications) example.

Comment: Ok ,so will the kernel identify the Virtual Net card so that the apps can access the LTE packet network or will have to do that over AT commands  . Also will the GPS NMEA  port be available over usb .Or the usb port cannot be used and have to send the AT Commands over the built in TTL serial  .Does linux part of the android thing os mount the usb tty elements ?

Comment: @saniljhaveri Seems, now there is no way to use SIM700E via USB connection on Android Things. You can use UART connection (BCM14, BCM15 pins on RPi and 9,10 pins on SIM700 - but I'm not sure about SIM modue side pin numbers) and implement all communication (network/GPS etc.) in user-mode via AT-commands. All  `/dev/ttyUSBX` are virtual and created by driver - SIM700E didn't have 6 serial ports. GPS data can be available via `AT+CGPS` (and other) commands, not via separate USB connection. Even if Linux part сan mount the usb tty you can't get their data in your app (see: "You cannot...")

Comment: @saniljhaveri And yes: "the usb port cannot be used and have to send the AT Commands over the built in TTL serial".

Comment: Thanks your  for that info was really helpful

Comment: @saniljhaveri And also, you can use USB<->UART converters on RPi side to connect to SIM700 module if you lack of UARTs (USB<->UART converters are supported by Android Things) http://nilhcem.com/android-things/usb-communications.

Comment: Will the network communication using  "AT commands "over the TTL serial be fast enough to make high data rate ftp calls ,will it be practically be vaible . Just curious  what if the Linux part is able to mount the COM can I access it over peripheralmanager().cos in that case the GPS will intigerate very well using user-driver app

Comment: Anyway all connection goes via SIM700 module and it's AT-commands. USB or UART - just interfaces (also, seems, SIM7000 supported I2C, but I didn't use it with GSM/GPRS modules). I'm already implemented UART connection on RPi with Android Things at `460800` baud and seems it's possible even at `921600`. Seems there is no problem with FTP connections at that rates. And GPS is not so fast. There is no problem with GPS and UART.